# Set a property name based on instance name in java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class like this (which I am developing)-

```
public class Comp { private String name; }
```

It is used in some other classes(which will be used by others and not in my control), like this

```
Comp username; 
Comp password;
```

What I want is, to set the name of the Comp object automatically same as the name of the instance created. That is in my case, it should return like this -

```
username.getName() -> "username"
password.getName() -> "password"
```

I need to do this on my side(that is, in the Comp class). Is this possible to achieve ?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You have to understand that instances don't have a name. Variables, on the other hand, do so.

Comment: Can this be done using custom annotations ? Something like this  - 
`@MyComp(name = "userName")`
`Comp username;`
If possible, how ?

Comment: Yes, this could be a way. Simply asking for "how" is too broad for SO. Go and read about annotations - especially custom ones. There are a ton of articles about that topic. But the more important question is: Why do you need that? I guess that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).